# Ormlite: How to order by a Date with a Data Type = String? Where sort will think of it as a date and not a string?

Tags: java, android, sql, ormlite

I have this:

```
 @DatabaseField(columnName = "DATE_TRAVEL", dataType = DataType.DATE_STRING,
        format = "dd-MM-yyyy")
public Date dateTravel;
```

When i use this

```
    Where<RoadTravelTableFile, Integer> queryBuilder = getHelper()
            .getRoadTravelTableFileIntegerDao().
                    queryBuilder().orderBy("DATE_TRAVEL",false).where().eq("main_id", Integer.parseInt(s));
```

The result is

30-09-14

16-11-14

12-10-14

12-09-15

09-10-14

It sorted it but, It thinks that it is a string.. Is there a way with this?

Comment: Well, one idea is use "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: That will work but the local format here is dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I had done what you advised and just use a locale conversion code to transfer it back to dd-MM-yyyy. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
class StringAsDateComparator implements Comparator<String>
{
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    public int compare(String lhs, String rhs)
    {
        return dateFormat.parse(lhs).compareTo(format.parse(rhs));
    }
}

Collections.sort(list, new StringDateComparator());
```

Try to implement a Comparator object that translates your strings to dates before comparing them and SimpleDateFormat object will perform the conversion.

Comment: I converted my ormlite query to a cursor. So I could not use this on my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can get data, then save to a list, and use below code to parse your date (string) to milliseconds, then sort it and show.

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(input);
long milliseconds = date.getTime();
```

Comment: I converted my ormlite query to a cursor. So I could not use this on my scenario.